# Picturebox movement out of sync

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-core, picturebox

Background: I'm trying to make a Flappy Bird-esque game in Visual Basic to familiarise myself with the language (I'm going to need to code with it for the next 2 years, I don't really get a choice).

The issue is with continuous movement of the pipes. The pipes are generated every 1200ms. The game checks for each control tagged `"pipe"` and `"score"` and moves it based on another timer with interval 60ms. Code for `gameloop` timer:

```vb
    Private Sub gameloop_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gameloop.Tick
        ' continuous movements
        player.Top += 10
        For Each c As Control In Controls
            If c.Tag = "pipe" Or c.Tag = "score" Then
                If c.Left < -40 Then ' checking if it's off screen, then removing it if so
                    Controls.Remove(c)
                Else ' if it's on screen, move it towards the player
                    c.Left -= 10
                End If
            End If
            If c.Tag = "collider" Or c.Tag = "pipe" Then ' checking for collision
                If player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds) Then
                    resetgame()
                End If
            End If
            If c.Tag = "score" Then ' scoring if player goes between
                If player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds) Then
                    Controls.Remove(c)
                    score += 1
                    scorelabel.Text = "Score: " & score
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

The bottom pipe and the scoring zone both move in sync with one another, but the top one seemingly lags behind a little bit (all 3 should move together), and gets progressively worse as the game goes, [see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtpt.jpg) Scoring zone is made pink for clarity.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. I checked the elapsed time for both the `gameloop` and `pipegen` timer, the code for both of which executes well within the timer interval. I also tried replacing the logic with a case statement but it still didn't change the desynchronisation. I personally couldn't find anything related to this online. Is it an issue with pictureboxes, VB or have I made a silly mistake (which is entirely possible, I'm very new to the language).

[Here's the full code on pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/aEVZke5j)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major error I made in the code was removing from an array while looping through it. Instead I made a list of controls to delete and looped through that afterwards:

```vb
    ' game logic
    Private Sub gameloop_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gameloop.Tick
        ' list of things to remove
        Dim removethese As New List(Of Control)
        ' continuous movements
        player.Top += 10
        For Each c As Control In Controls
            If c.Tag = "pipe" Or c.Tag = "score" Then
                If c.Left < -40 Then ' checking if it's off screen, then removing it if so
                    removethese.Add(c)
                Else ' if it's on screen, just move it towards the player
                    c.Left -= 10
                End If
            End If
            If c.Tag = "collider" Or c.Tag = "pipe" Then ' checking for collision
                If player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds) Then
                    resetgame()
                End If
            End If
            If c.Tag = "score" Then ' scoring if player goes between
                If player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds) Then
                    removethese.Add(c)
                    score += 1
                    scorelabel.Text = "Score: " & score
                End If
            End If
        Next
        For Each c As Control In removethese
            Controls.Remove(c)
        Next
    End Sub
```

All the pipes now move in sync so I did the same for the `destroy()` function, I no longer need to call it 3 times for it to work.

```vb
    Public Sub destroy()
        ' list of things to remove
        Dim temp As New List(Of Control)
        ' collecting controls to remove
        For Each c As Control In Controls
            If c.Tag = "pipe" Or c.Tag = "score" Then
                temp.Add(c)
            End If
        Next
        ' removing controls
        For Each c As Control In temp
            Controls.Remove(c)
        Next
    End Sub
```